# how call jquery plugin function inside controller in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using below code inside document ready function

```
 toastr.clear();
 toastr.options.closeButton = true;
 toastr.info('Message with a close button', '');
```

and its working fine. i have confusion to call mentioned function in controller.

Comment: you could do the same thing inside you controller, `toastr` object will be available there

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using an Angular toastr instead: https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr

Then you are away from the pain of integrating jQuery with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Right way is to create directive for calling jquery plugins. But if it's quick fix you can inject $element into controller. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514484/why-is-element-available-injected-in-controller) related question.