# $injector:unpr :: Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- DragulardndCtrl

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, dragular

I am using [this](https://luckylooke.github.io/dragular/#/docs/exampleBasicWithModel) example

I am doing exactly the same but I am getting the following error

`angular.js:14525 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $elementProvider <- $element <- DragulardndCtrl
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/unpr?p0=%24elementProvider%20%3C-%20%24element%20%3C-%20DragulardndCtrl
        at angular.js:66
        at angular.js:4789
        at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4944)
        at angular.js:4794
        at getService (angular.js:4944)
        at injectionArgs (angular.js:4969)
        at Object.instantiate (angular.js:5015)
        at $controller (angular.js:10881)
        at Object.link (angular-route.js:1214)
        at angular.js:1346 "<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">"`

I have generated the project with yeoman angular.The codes are given below

`Controller :`

```
angular.module('dragdropApp')
  .controller('DragulardndCtrl', ['$scope', '$element', 'dragularService', function TodoCtrl($scope, $element, dragularService) {
    $scope.items1 = [{
      content: 'Move me, but you can only drop me in one of these containers.'
    }, {
      content: 'If you try to drop me somewhere other than these containers, I\'ll just come back.'
    }, {
      content: 'Item 3'
    }, {
      content: 'Item 4'
    }];
    $scope.items2 = [{
      content: 'Item 5'
    }, {
      content: 'Item 6'
    }, {
      content: 'Item 7'
    }, {
      content: 'Item 8'
    }];
    var containers = $element.children().children();
    dragularService([containers[0],containers[1]],{
      containersModel: [$scope.items1, $scope.items2]
    });
  }])
```

**HTML:View**

```
<div class='tableRow'>
       <div class='containerVertical'>
           <div ng-repeat="item in items1">{{item.content}}</div>
       </div>
       <div class='containerVertical'>
           <div ng-repeat="item in items2">{{item.content}}</div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tableRow">
       <div class="container">
           <div>Items1:
               <br/>{{items1 | json}}</div>
       </div>
       <div class="container">
           <div>Items2:
               <br/>{{items2 | json}}</div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

I have used exactly the same code from the above-mentioned link.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code snippet so we can help you

Comment: updated .  ihave used the example code

Comment: I think it need Jquey which you forgot to include

Comment: it's a bad habit to use `$element` service in angular js controller.

Comment: but in example its written like that. what does that mean ?

Comment: Can you provide your whole HTML code please?

Comment: done  .... its there

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12501422/3455035), probably the url example doesn't has full code of html., try wrapping it in form

Comment: $element should be used only in directive controller, in the demo it was probably used just for dev testing and it was never replaced by production example, feel free to make PR to change it. Further reading about the $element: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26006334/861615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove $element dependecy, it is not needed for dragular. It only needs some array-like collection of elements which are considered to be containers. It can be

```
containers = [ document.getElementById('container1'), document.getElementById('container1') ]
```

or

```
containers = document.getElementsByClassname('container')
```

or

```
containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container')
```

or if you are using jQuery

```
containers = $('.container')
```

etc..

Comment: Perfect . thank you so much .. I have misunderstood few things. and now its clear. Thanks to you :D

Comment: I am glad it was helpful :) I wish I could write better docs, but I have not much time for it :/